# replace objectManger

Tags: magento2, email-templates, review

I have a phtml file. I want to get the product short description by SKU.
I can use ObjectManager to do the work.  But looks like this is not a proper way to do it.
Anyone can help with recommendation to replace ObjectManager method? Thanks!

```
<?= $block->getProductName($item->getProductId()) ?>
<?= $item->getProductId() ?>
<?= $item->getSku() ?>
<?php
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

   $currentproduct = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')->get($item->getSku());
   echo $currentproduct ->getShortDescription();
?>
```

rest of the code

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); ?>
<?php /** @var $items \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */ $items = $block->getOrder(); ?>
<?php if ($items): ?>
    <?php
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $order = $item->getOrder();
    }

    ?>
    <div style="width:100%;padding:10px 0 20px 0;height:auto;min-height:360px" class="review-email-form-wrapper">
        <p><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('your purchased items:') ?></p>
        <ul>
            <?php /** @var $item \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
            <?php $productUrl=$block->getProductReviewUrl($item->getProductId()) ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($productUrl) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductName($item->getProductId()) ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <p><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Thankyou for your feedback', $order->getStore()->getGroup()->getName()); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please put your layout file that declares that phtml file and the block class that the phtml using, so I can help.